# idiom: Pro convento nostro proximo

Tags: idiom

In the novice book, Musici Bremae, the author several times uses a phrase that appears to be some kind of idiom. For example:

> Gratias ago. Pro convento nostro proximo.

What does this mean?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? It would be easier to interpret the meaning from that.

Comment: @TuomoSipola I am asking about an idiom, not the translation of a specific passage. If you don't know the idiom, then you don't know it.